# what does this lt mean in jstl?

Tags: jstl

the following   code has a condition that has `lt` i was searching in the net but could not really understand what the `lt` means. Please explain. I am sure that this question will invoke me some down vote but i have no other  go other than posting this here.

```
<c:if test="${currentPage lt noOfPages}">
            <td><a href="employee.do?page=${currentPage + 1}">Next</a></td>
        </c:if>
```

Thanks and Regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

lt is shorthand for `less than` or `<`. Being so short, I can understand that it's difficult to search for.

Answer (score 3):

lt is an `EL` operator ([reserved word](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro7.html)) - less then `<`